# Is it possible to have file and folder names in the same JSON for Google Drive?

Tags: json, rest, google-drive-api

Is it possible to get folder name and file name in the same JSON for Google Drive?

Currently I can get file name with folder ID, but ID is not enough, I need name of the folder too.

```
mimeType ='application/vnd.google-apps.file'
```

Here parents is the ID of the folder

```
 {
       "id": "ID of the file",
       "name": "Tab 1 document",
       "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
       "parents": [
        "ID of the folder"
       ]
      },
```

And by running this query it brings name of the folders

```
mimeType= 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'

 {
   "id": "ID of the folder",
   "name": "Name of the folder",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "parents": [
    "Parent ID of this folder"
   ]
  },
```

To my understanding this should bring both file and folder name

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and mimeType ='application/vnd.google-apps.file'
```

but it brings

```
200

- Show headers -

{
 "files": [
 ]
}
```

I am doing all these queries in

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modifications?

#### Modification 1 :

In your question, `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and mimeType ='application/vnd.google-apps.file'` means the case that 2 mimeTypes occur simultaneously. How about the following modified query using `or`?

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.file'
```

#### Modification 2 :

In my environment, when `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.file'` was used as a query, no files was output. I don't know the reason. I'm sorry. If you are the same situation with me, how about using a following query?

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or ...
```

If you want to output other mimeTypes, you can check [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry. At that time, please tell me.